# Vue - Activate VNode Adjustment

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a *Vue* directive, which adds a conditional class to the VNode. Here is a short extract:

```
Vue.directive('editable', {
  bind (el, binding, vnode) {
    vnode.data.class = {'hidden': var}
  }
})
```

For testing propose, I replaced `var` with `true`, just to see if this part of the implementation works.
If I check the VNodes data now, I can see this conditional class and it looks like if I've add this directly to the element in the template. But in contrast the class is not added to the DOM element and so the classes properties are not visible.
So how can I make this changes on the VNode be kinda active?
Thanks!

Comment: I guess u have a typo and mean "add". And then yes, I want to add the css class `hidden`, if the variable is `true`. So like its typically done in Vue, but by using a directive, instead of doing it on the element directly.

Comment: sry for the typo......

Comment: No, was just to clear the base on which I answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument you get is `el` this is the element that the directive is present on.

You can directly use this argument to manipulate the DOM element in your case adding a new CSS class

```
Vue.directive('editable', { 
    bind (el, binding, vnode) { 
         if(condition){
             el.className += " " + "hidden";
         }
   }
})
```

Comment: Sry, but that doesn't help. Your condition is evaluate once after the binding. That does not work, if the conditions gets true later. I want something like [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax) where the class can be toggle, based on a data object.

Comment: @weilbith then you should use the plain `:class`  bindings